# Geometric description of span of 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I have searched a lot about how to write geometric description of span of 3 vectors, but couldn't find anything. There are lot of questions about geometric description of 2 vectors (Span ={v1,V2})
How can I describe 3 vector span?

Question is as follows:

= [−1 2 1] ,  = [5 0 2] ,  = [−3 2 2] ,  = [10 6 9] ,  = [−6 9 12]
       ℎ {, , }    ℎ 
  {, , }

I have done the first part, please guide me to describe it geometrically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find whether some vector $x$ lies in the the span of a set $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ in some vector space in which you know how all the previous vectors are expressed in terms of some basis, you have to find the solution(s) of the equation
$$
a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n = x
$$
where you have to find all $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ that satifay the equation. If there are no solutions, then the vector $x$ is not in the span of $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$. If there is at least one solution, then it is in the span.

For the geometric discription, I think you have to check how many vectors of the set  = [−1 2 1] ,  = [5 0 2] ,  = [−3 2 2] are linearly independent. If there is only one, then the span is a line through the origin. If there are two then it is a plane through the origin. If all are independent, then it is the 3-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks, but i did that part as mentioned.
I am asking about the second part of question "geometric description of span{v1v2v3}

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: if you have any example solution of these three cases, please share it with me :) would really appreciate it.

Comment: don't you know how to check linear independence, ? it is just to solve a linear system, The equation in my answer is that system in vector form.